# UIMA RUTA CAP Annotation Issues

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm using Uima Ruta 2.8.1 Version.In this, Symbols like Δ(U+2206) were coming under CAP Annotation.Why its Happening can anyone explain?.

Input :
Δ

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it. Can you provide more information about the execution environement and encoding settings? CAP is defined as Unicode \p{Uppercase}+